# Azure AD Auth with Angular and .NETCore2 WEBAPI

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to add authentication to my app using Azure AD

Right now my flow is like

User -> AngularApp -> Azure Login -> AngularApp w/token -> API Call to backend w/token -> API Backend verifies token with Azure each call

I have following questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Every API call is verified with azure. Is is required?
3. Should i have two different client id for UI and API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

This is the standard way.

> Every API call is verified with azure. Is is required?

Your API back-end does not verify the token with AAD each time.
It downloads the public signing keys for Azure AD at startup (if you use standard components), and verifies the token using them.

> Should i have two different client id for UI and API?

When you make a v2 application through the new App registrations experience, you can define the front-end and back-end API in a single app quite nicely.
You can also define them as separate apps.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean better? (less redirects?)

What you describe is a standard OpenID Connect flow that is used all over web right now. Whenever you are using your google, facebook, github login to log to some other page you are using that standard.

It is pretty secure and easy way of doing authorization/authentication on the web these days.

A little side note make sure that the token is valid for appropriate amount of time.

Comment: by better i mean, any better approach, yeah maybe less redirects also. Is it fine to call azure each time? Also if i follow this approach should i keep two seperate clientIds or same clientId for both ui and api?

Comment: There is no way to do less redirects. The spec is very specific on how to exchange credential for a token. As for token verification by Azure it is an interesting one. As the answer is no, once you have the token all the information you need to verify that it's valid are encoded in the token. What is your backend? Something in java by any chance?

Comment: only communication with the Aure should be to get the certificate used to sign the token.

Comment: Thanks
Backend is in .netCore

Comment: then i can't help you with the details. But would take a closer look at how the token is validated by your services. If you have a separate library that does that for you, maybe the problem is there.